# C program to reverse content of a file and write that to another file

Tags: c, pointers, input, incompatibletypeerror, reversing

I'm having issues with an assignment where I have to take the contents of one file into a buffer, reverse those contents, and write them to another file. This program NEEDS to utilize two functions that look like this:

- `int read_file( char* filename, char **buffer );`
- `int write_file( char* filename, char *buffer, int size);`

so far my files look like this:

file_utils.h

```
 #ifndef UTILS_H
 #define UTILS_H
      int read_file(char* filename, char **buffer);
      int write_file(char* filename, char *buffer, int size);
 #endif
```

file_utils.c

```
 #include "file_utils.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <font1.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int read_file(char* filename, char **buffer) {
      FILE* file1;
      file1 = fopen(filename, "r");

      //gets the size of the file
      struct stat st;
      stat(filename, &st);
      int size = st.st_size;

      buffer = malloc(size);
      read(file1, &buffer, 1);
      return size;
 }

 int write_file(char* filename, char*buffer, int size) {
      FILE* file2;
      file2 = fopen(filename, 'w');

      for (int k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
          char* x = &buffer + k;
          fprintf(file2, "%s", x);
      }
      printf(filename, '\O');
      return 1;
 }
```

reverse.c

```
 #include "file_utils.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <font1.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      char* buffer;
      char* filename1;
      char* filename2;
      int filesize;

      filename1 = argv[1];
      filename2 = argv[2];

      filesize = read_file(filename1, &buffer);
      write_file(filename2, buffer, filesize);

      return 0;
 }
```

and that's all there is. I run it using "clang file_utils.c reverse.c" and I get warnings for file_utils.c like

- `incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int" to parameter of type 'const char *'` (for the line file1 = fopen(filename, 'r')
- `incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'FILE *' (aka 'struct_IO_FILE*') to parameter of type 'int'` (for the line read(file1, &buffer, 1);)
- the same warning as the first one but for the line file2 = fopen(filename, 'w');
- and `incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char **'; dereferences with *` (for the line char* x = &buffer + k;)

on top of all this when I continue on to run the executable as such

```
./a.out file1 file2
```

where file 1 has text that should be reversed into file 2, I get a segmentation fault.

Any insight into things I can fix will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first error/warning is because you pass `'r'` when you need `"r"`. And the same goes for that third bullet.

Comment: First it's `"r"` (not `'r'`). The double quote is a *string*, the single quote is an *integer*.

Comment: Is this a homework, by the way?

Comment: that was my bad, the actual code had single quotes, but I have changed that and now the only errors I get are
- incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'FILE *' (aka 'struct _IO_FILE *') to parameter of type 'int' in regards to the line (read(file1, &buffer, 1);
- incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char **'; dereferences with * in regards to the line (char* x = &buffer + k;)

Comment: Also, did you skip error checking to post less code? Or you do not do any such checks?

Comment: Type man read to see what you must pass ro it. Hint. You should be using fread. Do man fread

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to `free()` your allocated buffer.

Comment: This is homework.  I'm the professor who assigned it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, without testing, I see these bugs:

`buffer = malloc(size);` should be `*buffer = malloc(size);`

... because `buffer` is a pointer to pointer to `char`, you need to
dereference it once.

`read(file1, &buffer, 1);` should be `fread(*buffer, 1, size, file1);`

... because you opened `file1` with `fopen`, so it's `FILE *`. `read` is
Unix I/O, not stream I/O, and doesn't use `FILE *`.

`file2 = fopen(filename, 'w');` should be `file2 = fopen(filename, "w");`

The second argument should be a "string" (pointer to `char` or array of
`char`). `'w'` is a single `char`.

`char* x = &buffer + k;` should be `char *x = buffer + k;`

`buffer` is a pointer to `char`, so you want to use it directly, not
take its address. Also note the style of putting `*` next to the
variable instead of the type. This is a good habit, because these
do not mean the same thing:

```
char *a, *b, *c;   /* three pointers */
char* a, b, c;     /* one pointer, two chars */
```

`fprintf(file2, "%s", x);` should be `fprintf(file2, "%c", *x);`

The first form treats `x` as the beginning of a string and will output
everything from that point onward until it hits a NUL terminator. You
want to output only one `char`, so use the `%c` specifier, and
dereference `x` to get a `char`.

A better way would be `fwrite(x, 1, 1, file2);`

`printf(filename, '\O');` is not needed and doesn't do what you think.
It looks like you intended to write a NUL at the end. That would be
`'\0'` (zero), not `'\O'` (letter O). In any case, it's not needed or
wanted. NUL is used to terminate a string in C, not a file. Your output
file will be one character longer than it should be if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

The most important issue with your code is here

```
      char* x = &buffer + k;
      fprintf(file2, "%s", x);
```

perhaps you mean

```
      char *x = buffer + k;
      fprintf(file2, "%c", *x);
```

You also, are mixing IO functions. For a `FILE *` object you should use `fread()` instead of `read()`, there should be an *incompatible arguments* warning from the compiler.

If there are no warnings (*BTW `char *x = &buffer + k` should trigger another warning*), then you should probably enable them explicitly so that your compiler can help you figure out other problems.

Also, check that `file1` is not `NULL` after `fopen()`, check that `fread()` did read the requested amount, in general check for every possible error which you can easily infer from the return value of the implied function, if you don't know the meaning of such value then READ THE DOCUMENTATION before using such function.

Comment: I made the initial change you suggested and received the warning "format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *'

Comment: Note the `*` before the `x`!

Answer (score 1):

And finally all together:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_file(char* filename, char **buffer) {
  FILE* file1;
  file1 = fopen(filename, "r");

  //gets the size of the file
  struct stat st;
  stat(filename, &st);
  int size = st.st_size;

  *buffer = malloc(size);
  fread(*buffer, size, 1, file1);
  fclose(file1);

  return size;
}

void write_file(char* filename, char*buffer, int size) {
  FILE* file2 = fopen(filename, "w"); int k;

  for (k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    fwrite(buffer + k, 1, 1, file2);
  }

  fclose(file2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char* buffer;
  char* filename1;
  char* filename2;
  int filesize;

  filename1 = "input.txt";
  filename2 = "reverse.txt";

  filesize = read_file(filename1, &buffer);
  write_file(filename2, buffer, filesize);

  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

with a live [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMN2ZGTnd3a3JmMUU). Please add checks for all return values, like `malloc()` does not return `NULL`.